# XML serialization and deserialization - nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a question about XML serialization and deserialization. Does the serialization class have to be exactly the same same as the XML. Can the order be different?

What happens if the XML has one fewer node then the class has?

And if I have many different XML coming in with different XML structure, how can I handle this different structure in the serialization class?

Thanks

Comment: The question is too generic - you should add some examples of the XML and of your classes.

Comment: These are things you could easily find out yourself - by writing test-code to try it out. May I suggest the excellent tool LINQPad? =)

Comment: Generally a good question arises when you try to do something yourself and you get stuck at a certain point.  Try it yourself and tell us what you can't get to work.

Comment: To what @mydogisbox said: this site *will reward effort*. If we see you made some, you'll get more responses. You can ask a "how do I?" question if it's one of those tricky items, but what you've asked is a real simple google search away. SO is a site to get you over the hump. I still left an answer as it only took about 30 seconds, but this is generally how the site works. You try and we help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class properties do not really have an ordering, so the ordering of the nodes in the XML does not have any particular meaning - it can be anything.

If a node is missing in the XML the corresponding class property won't be set - so it will have its default value, or whatever value the class construuctor set it to.

Different XML structures can be handled by the same class, with some restrictions though - without specific examples it is diffcult to say.

Answer (score 1):

The order doesn't matter, as long as your properties, fields, etc. are properly matched up with an xml node.

Also, if the xml has one less node, then that property won't get a deserialized value for it, that's all.

The structure is VERY important, but not the order. This is a pretty broad question, but I'd advise you go read up on it and look at some examples.

Look at these to get you started a bit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.100).aspx